# How to Use preg_replace to make spaces and capitals?

Tags: php, regex, web, preg-replace

I'm trying to convert a variable that say has, "hello-big-boy" or "hello-big" or even just say, "hello" into a variable that would have all the dashes converted to spaces, and the first letter of each word as a capital. So "hello-big-boy" would become Hello Big Boy, and "hello-big" would become Hello Big, and "hello" would become Hello.

Any help is much appreciated guys! Thanks :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since there is only a minor replace , you could avoid making use of `regex` and go with the native PHP functions.

```
<?php
$str='hello-big-boy';
echo ucwords(str_replace('-',' ',$str)); //"prints" Hello Big Boy
```

[<kbd>Demo</kbd>](https://eval.in/102086)

Comment: Thanks bro! Worked like a charm.